# Can you link action verbs with verbs of being in a sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs, phrases

Can you link action verbs with verbs of being in a sentence? As in say

- *These are people who think critically, solve problems collaboratively, and are prepared to thrive in a global society*.

Comment: It's okay but I'd reword to "These are people who ... collaboratively, and **prepare themselves** to thrive in a global society."

Comment: So what you mean is this: can one use ellipsis to connect normal and auxiliary verbs?

Comment: It's ordinary conjunction reduction, so as long as the deleted material (_who_ in this case) is repeated, it doesn't matter whether what's left is a verb or a noun, and it certainly doesn't matter what selectional restraints it has.

Comment: Yes, of course you can, no problem. Examples... Adjective: *These are people who **think** critically and [who] **are** happy.* Past participle adjective: *These are people who **think** critically and [who] **are** prepared.* Passive voice: *These are people who **think** critically and [who] **are **persecuted.*

Comment: I'd prefer << These are people who think critically, who solve problems collaboratively, and who are prepared to thrive in a global society. >> stylewise.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; there is no rule that would prohibit joining these three verb phrases. It may not sound very good, but that's a matter of taste.

The only potential issue would occur if you tried to perform subject-auxiliary inversion on it. *This* sentence *is* incorrect, and somewhat difficult to fix:

> * **Do you** think critically, solve problems collaboratively, and are prepared to thrive in a global society?

Comment: Right, because _be prepared to_ wouldn't require _Do_-support in a question; _are_ is already  an auxiliary verb, so it would front in a question and not _do_.

Comment: It may be ungrammatical (well, it definitely is), but it is the type of grammatical error that you’re quite likely to hear from native speakers – the sort where you start the sentence one way, and then halfway through realise that how you plan on finishing the sentence doesn’t fit, so you just sort of plow on through and end up with half of each in something which is not actually grammatical, but which everyone understands and parses with no problems. This one’s quite easy to fix, though: just un-reduce the ellipsis and end with, “… and are you prepared to thrive in a global society?”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But that "fixed" version means something different; it involves asking three separate questions instead of one.

Comment: How are getting a *do* in there? Inverted: *Are these people who think critically, solve problems collaboratively, and are prepared to thrive in a global society?*

Comment: @TinfoilHat I mean performing it on the coordination, not on the entire sentence.